# C# collection or array with string keys and values of different types

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, dictionary, collections

I need to store data about one article in multiple fields, 3 fields in this example:

```
article["title"]       = "Article Title";        // string
article["description"] = "Article Description";  // string
article["total_pages"] = 15;                     // int
```

Then I need to be able to use the stored data:

```
int pages = article["total_pages"]; // cast not required

MessageBox.Show(pages.ToString());    
MessageBox.Show(article["title"]);
```

**Question:**

What would be the proper way of storing data like this?

I could simply create variables like `string article_title`, `string article_description`, `int article_total_pages` but if the article actually has more than 10 fields, then the code gets quite messy.

**Edit:**

It's fine if all fields can be defined somewhere in one place. What I need is to be able to have a clean code when I use these data in the program.

E.g. `Article["Title"]` or `Article.Title` (very clean usage)

Comment: Why not create a Article class? And maybe some sub-classes?

Answer (score 2):

create a class for that case

```
class Article
{
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try a dictionary with string keys and dynamic values:

```
var article = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

article["title"] = "Article Title";
article["description"] = "Article Description";
article["total_pages"] = 15;

int pages = article["total_pages"];
string title = article["title"];
```

You can also achieve a similar effect with an ExpandoObject:

```
dynamic article = new ExpandoObject();
article.Title = "Article Title";
article.Description = "Article Description";
article.TotalPages = 15;

int pages = article.TotalPages;
string title = article.Title;
```

Comment: and how do you manage a list of articles? with a list of dictionaries? that question is about avoiding messy code

Comment: @fubo "I need to store data about one article"

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary with `object` as type. Then wrap it and to avoid casting it we use generics when fetching it:

```
class ObjectStore
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _objects = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public void Add(string key, object obj)
    {
        _objects[key] = obj;
    }

    public object Get<T>(string key)
    {
        object obj;
        if(_objects.TryGetValue(key, out obj))
        {
            return (T)obj;
        }

        return default(T);
    }

    public object this[string key]
    {
        get { return _objects[key]; }
        set { _objects[key] = value; }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ObjectStore os = new ObjectStore();
os["int"] = 4;
os.Add["string"] = "hello";

// With generic method (no cast)
int num = os.Get<int>("int");
string str = os.Get<string>("string");

// Or...
int num = (int)os["int"];
string str = (string)os["string"];
```

Comment: how do you iterate this?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you store like information in a class, grouping it together logically to represent an object. For example, an `Article` class.

```
public class Article
{
    public string Title { get;set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can have an `IList<Article>` or `IDictionary<Article>` as needed. Either way you could use LINQ to filter or an select articles that match a desired criteria.